# use sp() package to compute the shortest distance between 2 sets of coordinates

Tags: r, apply, geospatial, distance, r-sp

I have two sets of coordinates (base & target) as two data frames.

```
base.df <- data.frame(cbind(LONG = c(-73.94006,-73.95616,-73.86548,-73.99118,-73.99801,
                                 -73.96208,-73.95544,-74.09251,-73.94317,-73.98913),
                            LAT = c(0.78963,40.65378,40.83767,40.75533,40.74759,
                                40.71327,40.81450,40.62554,40.83660,40.57415)))

target.df <- data.frame(cbind(long = c(-74.00754,-74.01252,-74.00525,-74.00594,-74.00668,-73.99290),
                              lat = c(40.70347,40.71007,40.71005,40.71546,40.71976,40.71521)))
```

My goal is to take each row of the base dataframe and use `spDistsN1()` to get different distances between that row (base) and EVERY row of the target dataframe. Among many distances I want to the shorest distance (use `min()`?) and append that shortest distance to a new vector. After finishing, I should have only 10 data points that I could `cbind()` back the the base dataframe. I know `apply()` could be useful, but I am not super familiar with using that or writing functions in R, could someone please help?

Comment: Please avoid posting images. Post your data in text format, so everyone can use them.

Comment: thanks for reminding, I will change it by appending reproducible code

Comment: Just use `spDists` instead of `spDistsN1`. Start with `spDists(as.matrix(base.df),as.matrix(target.df),longlat=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to handle your task. Since you need matrices for `spDistsN1()`, I converted both data frames to matrix objects.  In the `lapply()` I calculated distances between each row in `base.df` and all rows in `target.df`. This creates ten lists. Each list represents each row in `base.df`. What you wanna do is to look for a minimum value in each list, which you can do with another `lapply()`. Finally, I added the result as `out` to `base.df` using `bind_cols()`.

```
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

base.mtx <- as.matrix(base.df)
target.mtx <- as.matrix(target.df)

lapply(1:nrow(base.df), function(x){
    spDistsN1(pts = target.mtx, pt = base.mtx[x, ])}) %>%
lapply(min) %>%
unlist %>%
bind_cols(base.df, out = .)

        LONG      LAT         out
1  -73.94006  0.78963 39.91389704
2  -73.95616 40.65378  0.07147727
3  -73.86548 40.83767  0.17672665
4  -73.99118 40.75533  0.03880045
5  -73.99801 40.74759  0.02914923
6  -73.96208 40.71327  0.03088100
7  -73.95544 40.81450  0.10612142
8  -74.09251 40.62554  0.11529521
9  -73.94317 40.83660  0.13118157
10 -73.98913 40.57415  0.13062385
```

Comment: You can just use `spDists`. Also, you should set `longlat=TRUE` I guess.